# RTK Query invalidateTags only after mutation "success"

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Hello am using RTK query for API interaction  but am facing some error, where I trigger mutation endpoint invalidation always executed if its error or success.

what i am searching for is Invalidate Tags on mutation success here is my code

Get Endpoints

```js
getPosts: builder.query({
      query: () => `/posts`,
      providesTags: ['Posts'],
      transformResponse: (response, meta, arg) => response.data,
      transformErrorResponse: (response, meta, arg) =>  response.data?.message ?? response ,
    })
```

mutation endpoint

```js
mutatePost: builder.mutation({   
      query: (data,id) => ({
        url: id?`/posts/${id}`: `/posts`,
        method: id?'PATCH':'POST',
        body: data,
      }),
    
      transformResponse: (response, meta, arg) => response.data,
      transformErrorResponse: (response, meta, arg) => response.data?.message ?? response , 
      invalidatesTags: ['Posts'],

    })
```

i tried all results available but not fit for my expection

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the callback notation

```js
invalidatesTags: (result, error) => error ? [] : ['Posts'],
```

Comment: Is there are any global setting, which can be set for all endpoints in api?

Comment: @AlexShul No, that would hardly make any sense since your api would contain all different kinds of tags (you are adhering to the rule to only have one api in your application, right?).

Comment: I think, that there are no sense in invalidating tags if mutation failed. I was surprised when I found out that RTK Query ignore errors in mutations. I think if there were some global settings to change this behavior then it would be useful.

Comment: @AlexShul What if the mutation was executed correctly on the server, but during receiving the response you get a network error? Then from the client perspective, the "mutation failed". Of course you would want to invalidate in that case. If you want different behavior in an invalidation case, you should do that with a manual implementation, probably looking at the error.

Comment: I agree, but I think that tags invalidation is necessary for all endpoints at least when we get 4XX status code and implementing this behaviour for each endpoint separately is not the best way